# fail to add new line to email body for sendmail -t | Unix |

Tags: shell

I have a Scenario where I am bit struggling to implement this simple change
Need to print Body text in proper format

Lets assume I have parameters defined :

```
EmailSubjectDemo="New Message : `date`"
EmailbodyDemo="Hi Bro How \\nare \\nyou"
EmailToDemo="abc@xyz.com,pqr@f.com"
EmailFromDemo="abc@yz.com,pqr@f.com"
```

**Now my Sendmail code :**

```
(
   echo "From : $EmailFromDemo"
   echo "To   : $EmailToDemo"
   echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
   echo "Subject: $EmailSubjectDemo"
   echo "Content-Type: text\html"
   echo -e "$EmailbodyDemo"

) sendmail -t
```

This `echo -e "$EmailbodyDemo"`  is not printing data in proper new line format
even i tried with `printf $EmailbodyDemo` but no luck

**Expected output of Email Body :**

```
Hi Bro How 
are you
```

**Note :**
*This -e and printf does not work at my end*

I am not allowed to create a separate text file and call it in `sendmail` code like `cat file.txt`

```
Hi Bro How 

are you
```

Any other approach is appreciated

Comment: add an empty newline between `content-type` and `body`. (also, anyway, instaed of using variables, use functions `emailbodydemo() { echo something; echo something else; }`). `I am not allowed` by whom? Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach worked for me

Writing the **Body text content** within `html tags`

```
#Pre-Defined parameters 

EmailSubjectDemo="New Message : `date`"
EmailbodyDemo="<html> <body> Hi Bro How <br> are <br> you </body> </html>"
EmailToDemo="abc@xyz.com,pqr@f.com"
EmailFromDemo="abc@yz.com,pqr@f.com"

#Sending mail 

(
   echo "From : $EmailFromDemo"
   echo "To   : $EmailToDemo"
   echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
   echo "Subject: $EmailSubjectDemo"
   echo "Content-Type: text\html"
   echo -e "$EmailbodyDemo"

) sendmail -t
```